# Add foreground color and central icon to clickable view

Tags: android, android-layout, click, android-drawable

I'm trying to achieve something like this!
[Alternative to check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQdhC.jpg)
How do I achieve this?

I tried creating a drawable with a central icon and a transparent background but the icon scales to fill the view when the drawable is set to the view foreground.

Also there is no support for setForground method for api level less than 23

I intend to achieve this dynamically when a view is clicked. Please help!!!

Comment: Try using gravity with an [XML bitmap](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#XmlBitmap) to prevent the drawable from filling the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve this view use  **relative layout** like below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp">

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/demo_img_4" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/transp_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#30000000"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //initialize views
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image_view = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    delete_btn = findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
    transp_ll = findViewById(R.id.transp_ll);

    //set transparent layout visibility gone
    transp_ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //set click listener
    image_view.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.delete_btn:
            //write here delete button click functionality..
            transp_ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.image_view:
            transp_ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems a good solution. but check there is no id set to `transp_ll, image_view and delete_btn` in the xml. Please update your solution

Answer (score 0):

You should add a transparent view that matches the parent dimensions over you view and add a image view in center of it. 
You can adjust your transparency level to get the desired effect